# Django and Javascript: Take Info From API And Save To Database

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

I'm very new to Javascript with Django and I'm looking for some basic info on how to take info from an API that has already been returned, and post it to the database. I have used views.py to take information and save it to the database, but I haven't done this with info from an API that is achieved in Javascript. My project is a weather app that gets info from OpenWeather for a city that the user types into a box, and that part works - the API information is returned. I currently have a model for each Location, I just don't know how to save it in the database.

Is this done through fetch, using POST? I am also slightly confused about how the urls would be setup. Any information, maybe some sample github code, could help :)

For example, if I want to get the location and then add it to my 'favorites' would something like this make sense? I know I would still need to make the view, and url.

```
const location_content = document.querySelector('#content').value;
function add_to_fav() {
  fetch('/favorites', {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify({
     location_content: location_content
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
});
localStorage.clear();
return false;
}
```

Here is my model for each city that is returned via the API:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Comment: have you configured django api for receiving payload from your frontend? if no, have a look into django rest api framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan thank you, I took a look at the documentation as well as many youtube tutorials. The thing that I am stuck on, is understanding the connection between how to return data from the API from using 'fetch' in Javascript, and then the code to save that to the database. For example, how would I assign the data I get back from the API, and then call that information in python, saving it to the database? I'm just stuck on that piece, and how they connect. If I could find some sample code for a project doing this with fetch, I feel like I could figure it out.